# How to create RGB image using GDAL C++?

Tags: gdal, c++

I'm working with GDAL using C++.

I've got a code to create a black-and-white image:

```
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDriver *pDriverTiff = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
GDALDataset *pNewDS;
pNewDS = pDriverTiff->Create(output, nCols, nRows, 1, GDT_UInt16, NULL);
double *transform = geotiff->get_transform();
pNewDS->SetProjection(geotiff->get_proj().c_str());
pNewDS->SetGeoTransform(geotiff->get_transform());
float *newRow = (float *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nCols);
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        newRow[j] = matrix[i * nCols + j];
    }
    pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, newRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
}
GDALClose(pNewDS);
GDALDestroyDriverManager();
```

And it works flawlessly.

But now I want to create a colored RGB image. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDriver *pDriverTiff = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
GDALDataset *pNewDS;
char* options[] = {"PHOTOMETRIC=RGB", "PROFILE=GeoTIFF"};
pNewDS = pDriverTiff->Create(output, nCols, nRows, 3, GDT_UInt16, options);
double *transform = geotiff->get_transform();
pNewDS->SetProjection(geotiff->get_proj().c_str());
pNewDS->SetGeoTransform(geotiff->get_transform());
float *newRow = (float *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(float)*nCols);
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        newRow[j] = matrix[i * nCols + j];
    }
    pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, newRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        newRow[j] = matrix[i * nCols + j];
    }
    pNewDS->GetRasterBand(2)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, newRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
}
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
        newRow[j] = matrix[i * nCols + j];
    }
    pNewDS->GetRasterBand(3)->RasterIO(GF_Write, 0, i, nCols, 1, newRow, nCols, 1, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
}
pNewDS->GetRasterBand(1)->SetColorInterpretation(GCI_RedBand);
pNewDS->GetRasterBand(2)->SetColorInterpretation(GCI_GreenBand);
pNewDS->GetRasterBand(3)->SetColorInterpretation(GCI_BlueBand);
GDALClose(pNewDS);
GDALDestroyDriverManager();
```

But the image is still black-and-white. How to make it colored?